# how to print some of tokens in a line in MapReduce format?

Tags: java, dictionary, hadoop, split, stringtokenizer

I'm writing a map function. I have a text file as:

```
364.2   366.6   365.2   0   0   1   10421
364.2   366.6   365.2   0   0   1   10422
```

I want to show column 1,3. This is my code but it shows all of the rows.

```
public static class SumMap extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text str = new Text();

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer lineIter = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "\\r?\\n");
        while (lineIter.hasMoreTokens()) {
            StringTokenizer tokenIter = new StringTokenizer(lineIter.nextToken(), "\\s+");
            while (tokenIter.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String v1 = tokenIter.nextToken();
                String v2 = tokenIter.nextToken();
                String c1 = tokenIter.nextToken();
                String c2 = tokenIter.nextToken();
                str.set(v1+c1);
                context.write(str, one);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In this code, the first should be split by line `("\\r?\\n")` and then for every row, splits by number or string or token by `("\\s+")`. Finally, print `v1+c1`. How do I change my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the number of tokens being generated and the number of tokens you are accessing. In the inner while loop, the number of tokens generated will be 7. But you are accessing only 4 of them at a time. What you gotta do is to access all the tokens at the same time. Since you needed only the 1 and 3 column, Retrieve them and store them separately.

```
public static class SumMap extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text str = new Text();

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer tokenIter = new StringTokenizer(lineIter.nextToken(), "\\s+");
        while (tokenIter.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String c1 = tokenIter.nextToken();
            String c2 = tokenIter.nextToken();
            String c3 = tokenIter.nextToken();
            String c4 = tokenIter.nextToken();
            String c5 = tokenIter.nextToken();
            String c6 = tokenIter.nextToken();
            String c7 = tokenIter.nextToken();
            str.set(c1+c3);
            context.write(str, one);
        }
    }
}
```

main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "sum");
        job.setJarByClass(SumMR.class);
        job.setMapperClass(SumMap.class);
//        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
//        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```

This is the modified code. If there's a problem, let me know!.

Comment: No, It does not work. I think should be change InputFormat.

Comment: `lineIter` doesn't do anything here. There will always be only one token

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't notice it. Thanks for pointing it out. @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

If you use TextInputFormat, the key of map is line number and the value is line content. You don't need split lines. just split each line:

```
@Override
protected void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] vals = value.toString().split("\\s+");
    if (vals.length == 7) {
        context.write(new Text(vals[0] + vals[2]), one);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you . It has not error but does not create output part-r-00000. Why? I'm new to hadoop.

Comment: Please add your driver and reducer

Comment: I added main code and update my question. I do not want to add Reducer now. just map.

Comment: `vals.length == 4` must be `vals.length == 7` and showed output. But output is not my desired output. Output is showed from end to first.

Comment: Do you need sorted output?

Comment: No, It does not matter not arranged keys. I just wanna know why records in output file were arranged from end to start?

Comment: I have no insight about it, read this link https://data-flair.training/blogs/map-only-job-in-hadoop-mapreduce/  how many mappers do u have?